# Access private members of class that is friends with parent class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Consider the following

```
class Base;

class A {
  int x;

  friend class Base;
};

class Base {
  protected:
    A a_obj;

  public:
    Base(){
      a_obj.x; // works
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Derived(){
      a_obj.x; // not accessible
    }
};
```

I could make public getters and setters for x, or make the object public, but that is not preferrable. Assuming there is a bunch of derived classes, adding `friend class Derived` in `class A` would make the code too verbose. Is there a way to say "A is friends with class Base and all it's children"

Comment: No there's no way to write such friend declarations. A friend is explicitly only for the class mentioned. On another note I think you need to reconsider your design, and instead of  using direct noun-to-class translation think about the *behavior* of the objects needed. So for example instead of trying to get the value of `x` directly, you ask the `a_obj` object to perform an action and get a result from that action.

Comment: your design needs a fix. Classes should not be granted access to members of all types derived from one base. Those members should be (protected) members of the base

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is what I would do. In this example it seems obvious to  just "reconsider the design" but this is just a distilled version of what I'm working on. In my example it would not be wise to make getters and setters as you recommended. Is there a non-verbose alternative to frienship that would allow this?

Comment: No I don't mean simple getters or setters, that's like using `friend` or making members all `public`. Instead I meant that call a member function of `a_obj` to perform an *action*, to do some calculation or other similar thing, and then return the result. Don't think of classes as simple containers or grouping of members, think of them in terms of some kind of behavior. For example a `Dog` class have the behavior `bark` and `eat` (among others), but you don't have access to the internal "members" of the dog (like how full it is).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In my project a better metaphor would be a room full of surgeons (derived classes) working on an unconscious patient (base class). Which doesn't make that much sense really (why is it derived anyway?). I realize now that it is better if make my class into just a data structure. I was hoping there was quick syntactical fix rather than a complete restructuring of my program. Oh well, you live and learn

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to say "A is friends with class Base and all it's children"

No.

What you *can* do is make the base a friend (as you did), and write a protected accessor in the base that the children can use to access the private member.

Answer (score 3):

In short, c++ rule is that friendship is not inheritable.
To achieve what you need, you can add static protected method as accessor in a Base class.
But, if you really need to make it w/o accessors or getters
you can make it with reinterpret_cast, but it would be hack and its not recommended.

Comment: Is there an alternative to friendship that would work without getters?

Comment: yes, as I stated in the answer you can make static protected method in the Base class, to access Base's friends private data. But if you consider static protected method of a Base class as getter, there is no way beside trick with reinterpret cast

Comment: @Trad_NotSuitedPC you can use public members as alternative. Or add public setters and getters in A

Comment: @armagedescu I explicitly stated that those were not preferrable

Comment: @Trad_NotSuitedPC No "trick" with `reinterpret_cast` "works". There are a small few valid uses for `reinterpret_cast`, and then there are "tricks" i.e. things the compiler will let you do but which are formally nonsense. One should not use the latter in any real code.

Comment: @Trad_NotSuitedPC well, for reinterpret cast you need to make another class A1 with public access rights to data members of interest, and same as class A in any other sense, then reinterpret cast pointer to A to pointer to A1, and then use data as such if pointer to A1 is non nullptr. But, again, it is not recommended way of using c++

Comment: @underscore_d Why would you not use this in any "real code". Yes in some cases it is non-portable but why shouldn't I use this?

Comment: @Trad_NotSuitedPC aside from being _fully_ non-portable, it's also devious and silly. just write good code, which doesn't need "tricks", please.

Comment: @underscore_d I'm confused what exactly constitutes "good code"

Comment: @Trad_NotSuitedPC It would use access specifiers properly and/or employ legitimate ways around them - not create an unrelated class that you hope has the same order and trick the compiler into reading the private member by pretending it's a member of the unrelated class.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to say "A is friends with class Base and all it's children"

No

You need to fix your design. Classes should not be granted access to members of all types derived from a base class. As per your code, I think you need to modify the private member of a class in the constructor of other class.

One possible solution is using parameterized constructor. You can call constructor of class `A` from classes `Base` and `Derived`.

```
class Base;

class A {
  int x;

public:
  A(int in): x(in)
  {

  }

};

class Base {
protected:
    A a_obj;

public:
    Base(int in): A(in)
    {

    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(): Base(5)
    {

    }
};
```